# Order of register stores in STP

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64

In AArch64 assembly, the following line

```
stp x25, x30, [sp,#48]
```

stores x25 at sp+48 and x30 at sp+56, right?

Comment: First register at lower address, yes I think so.  An AArch64 ISA manual should say.

Comment: Though it is interesting if the two stores appear as one or have a defined ordering relative to each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. From [this manual](https://developer.arm.com/docs/ddi0487/latest), page C6-1237 and following:

> #### Signed offset
>
> [...]
> ***64-bit variant***
>
> Applies when `opc == 10`.
>
> ```
> STP <Xt1>, <Xt2>, [<Xn|SP>{, #<imm>}]
> ```
>
> ***Decode for all variants of this encoding***
>
> ```
> boolean wback = FALSE;
> boolean postindex = FALSE;
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> #### Shared decode for all encodings
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> integer n = UInt(Rn);
> integer t = UInt(Rt);
> integer t2 = UInt(Rt2);
> [...]
> integer scale = 2 + UInt(opc<1>);
> integer datasize = 8 << scale;
> bits(64) offset = LSL(SignExtend(imm7, 64), scale);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> #### Operation for all encodings
>
> ```
> constant integer dbytes = datasize DIV 8;
>
> [...]
>
> if n == 31 then
>     CheckSPAlignment();
>     address = SP[];
> else
>     address = X[n];
>
> if !postindex then
>     address = address + offset;
>
> [...]
> data1 = X[t];
> [...]
> data2 = X[t2];
>
> Mem[address, dbytes, AccType_NORMAL] = data1;
> Mem[address+dbytes, dbytes, AccType_NORMAL] = data2;
> ```

Let's go through this, top to bottom. Your `stp x25, x30, [sp,#48]` is a 64-bit signed-offset `stp`, which decodes as:

```
n = 31
t = 25
t2 = 30
scale = 3 // since opc = 0b10
datasize = 64
offset = 48
```

Plug that into the operation pseudocode, substitute variables for their values, and you effectively get:

```
CheckSPAlignment();
Mem[SP[] + 48, 8, AccType_NORMAL] = X[25];
Mem[SP[] + 56, 8, AccType_NORMAL] = X[30];
```